# Is it possible to group MenuItems in a MenuBar in Vaadin?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I would like to group `MenuItems` together and then have a break/separator between them in my `MenuBar`. The classic example is a word processor menu where the cut, paste, copy actions are together and then you may have the undo, redo in another group, and so on. Is this possible within Vaadin?

By this I don't mean a line in the dropdown menu of the toolbar, but rather groups a space in the group of buttons in the toolbar. The screenshot below is from the Vaadin discussion forum.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to add a separator between two items:

```
item.addItem("Copy", null);
item.addItem("Paste", null);
item.addSeparator();
item.addItem("Test", null);
```

For space between two items, I would add a style name for an item and use CSS to add some space after the item:

```
Item paste = item.addItem("Paste", null);
paste.setStyleName("space-after");
```

Comment: This only adds a separator in the drop down menu of the toolbar, but what about adding a space between the buttons in the menu bar itself? This is why I asked for a break/seperator in the MenuBar and not the MenuItems. I can see however why it's not clear, it's a subtle distinction and for this I apologize. I'll edit the question to make this clearer.

Comment: Ah, I didn't read your original description carefully enough. Description about cut, copy and paste just lead me to think an edit drop down :)

Comment: No worries. What is your space after style? It's also not in the drop down menu... Basically I think you're still answering the same question...